# Benchmarking jasmine specs

Tags: javascript, testing, benchmarking, jasmine

Jasmine has a full suite timer out of the box.

What I would like is to be able to have a timer for each individual spec, and add this to the HTML reporter [or console log].

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

In Jasmine's TrivialReporter, defined in jasmine-html.js, following functions mark the start and end of running a spec

```
jasmine.TrivialReporter.prototype.reportSpecStarting
jasmine.TrivialReporter.prototype.reportSpecResults
```

You can write your code to start the timer in the first function and end it in second and then log the time either in console or HTML log